# Flutter: Unknown UI Spacing issues

Tags: flutter

I'm facing spacing issues below the Carousel Slider in my Flutter app. The problem occurs when I put a Column widget with a few widgets including a CarouselSlider inside a Container widget. For some reason, there is a big white space below it, which wasn't present at an earlier stage.

Attaching the code below along with a screenshot with reference to what I'm referring to:

```
class MiddleSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userName;

  const MiddleSection({
    Key? key,
    required this.userName,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final List<CategoryItem> categoryItems = [
      CategoryItem(
        imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage',
        label: 'Sports',
      ),
      CategoryItem(
        imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage',
        label: 'Art / Craft',
      ),
      CategoryItem(
        imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage',
        label: 'Art / Craft',
      ),
      CategoryItem(
        imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage',
        label: 'Art / Craft',
      ),
      CategoryItem(
        imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage',
        label: 'Art / Craft',
      ),
      CategoryItem(
        imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage',
        label: 'Art / Craft',
      ),
      CategoryItem(
        imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage',
        label: 'Art / Craft',
      ),
    ];

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // Set padding to zero
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero, // Set margin to zero
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF), // Added background color
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xFFBFBFBF), // Set to #BFBFBF
            width: 0.5, // Set border width
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                //height: 250.0,
                autoPlay: true,
                aspectRatio: 16/9,
                autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 5), // Delay set
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                viewportFraction: 1,
                //TODO: Add Indicators for the dots
                // onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                //   setState(() {
                //     _current = index;
                //   });
                // },
              ),
              items: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://firebasestorage.',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://firebasestorage.',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 73, vertical: 16),
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '$userName',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      color: Color(0xFFFFC107), // Yellow color for username
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: " what’s on your mind?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      color: Color(0xFF666666), // Changed to hex color #666666
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
            child: CarouselSlider.builder(
              itemCount: categoryItems.length,
              options: CarouselOptions(
                viewportFraction: 0.25,
                enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                padEnds: false,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex, int pageViewIndex) {
                return categoryItems[itemIndex];
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Flutter Spacing Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to wrap the carousel slider with sized box :

it's related to the `viewportFraction`, specify how much space will the element(image) will occupy from the screen , while the carousel slider occupies its space based on the size of it's children.

after the carousel get occupied say 100 as its height (which fits the image), you tell it to display an image in the quarter of the screen (25 height).

now, carousel stills occupying 100px while the image needs only 25px.

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MiddleSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userName;

  const MiddleSection({
    Key? key,
    required this.userName,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // Set padding to zero
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero, // Set margin to zero
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF), // Added background color
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xFFBFBFBF), // Set to #BFBFBF
            width: 0.5, // Set border width
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                //height: 250.0,
                autoPlay: true,
                aspectRatio: 16/9,
                autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 5), // Delay set
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                viewportFraction: 1,
                //TODO: Add Indicators for the dots
                // onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                //   setState(() {
                //     _current = index;
                //   });
                // },
              ),
              items: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  child: Image.asset('images/1.jpg'),
                ),
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                   child: Image.asset('images/1.jpg'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 73, vertical: 16),
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '$userName',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      color: Color(0xFFFFC107), // Yellow color for username
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: " what’s on your mind?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      color: Color(0xFF666666), // Changed to hex color #666666
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 50,width: double.infinity,
            child: CarouselSlider.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              options: CarouselOptions(
                viewportFraction: .25,
                enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                padEnds: false,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex, int pageViewIndex) {
                return Image.asset('images/1.jpg',);
              },
            ),
          ),

          Text('is There any White above me?',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20,),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way, I can define the sized box height to be dynamic?

Comment: @MrPool i think you should use LayoutBuilder as a parent widget with children of the carousel, so you can figure out how much space the carousel occupy, so you can fill specific percent of the carousel. eg: wrap the image in item builder of carousel with layout builder to get the constraints of the carousel.